# Style a certain <div> only on a page where the <html class="test">

Tags: html, css, joomla

I beleive it is something very simple for someone who is familiar with CSS (if it is possible at all)

I am using Joomla.

There is an option where I can add a class to the page.

For example if I set 'Page class' to 'test' it includes it in the  tag ....
 `<html class="test">`

Then I have a `<div class="page-masthead">` on all my pages.

**I want to put a background-image on this `<div class="page-masthead">`, only on the pages where `<html class="test">`**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write the css as follow when html tag takes *test* class, *page-masthead* div will take red background. you can change the css like

> background-image:url('images/img-url.png');

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" class="test">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
     <div class="page-masthead">
        <p>Lorem Ipsunm Dolor Sit Amet</p>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.test .page-masthead{
            background: red;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just prepend the class of `test` in your CSS style.

```
.test .page-masthead {
   background : url("your_image_path");
}
```